# Looking for an idiomatic and efficient python code for transforming json object

Tags: json, python-3.x

Looking for elegant ways:
The fields will be constant but the values can be variable strings or a set of enumerable string values (ex: "color" can be "RED", "BLUE" or "GREEN")
The objective is to transform json fields  to enum (or integers) where possible
A sample json object (will be more nested with more fields and values)
{

```
"@timestamp": "2023-05-09T11:33:09.000Z",

"@metadata": {
"beat": "filebeat",
"type": "_doc",
"version": "8.2.4",
"_id": "0c2d32ca",
"pipeline": "fbconst"
},
"event": {
"id": "0c2d32ca",
"category": "authentication",
"dataset": "o365.audit",
"module": "o365",
"code": "AzureActiveDirectoryStsLogon",
"kind": "event",
"type": [
  "start",
  "success1"
],
"outcome": "success",
"provider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
"action": "UserLoggedIn"
}
},
{
"@timestamp": "2023-05-09T11:33:09.000Z",
"@metadata": {
"beat": "filebeat2",
"type": "_doc",
"version": "8.2.3",
"_id": "0c2d32cb",
"pipeline": "fbconst"
},
"event": {
"id": "0c2d32cb",
"category": "security",
"dataset": "o365.audit",
"module": "o365",
"code": "AzureActiveDirectoryStsLogon",
"kind": "event",
"type": [
  "stop",
  "signoff"
],
"outcome": "failure",
"provider": "AzureActiveDirectory",
"action": "UserLoggedIn"
}
```

As we can see, keys can be enumerables and a few values as well
(ex: "beat" can take "filebeat" or "filebeat1" and no other values, so "filebeat" and "filebeat1" can be enums . same applies to other field values such as "sucess", "failure")

I tried by having a dictionary for each level of nested keys and values (a few values can be enumerables as well) and replacing in loop, its inefficient and not very elegant

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/), a cross-language specification for JSON 'typing'.
They have a nice [starter tutorial](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html), which covered pretty much exactly what you're trying to do. It requires writing a sort of 'format description file', which is a bit annoying, but if you do it properly, it becomes trivial to extedn your format in the future, which is awesome.

They also have a list existing parsers/validators for python, so you shouldn't have to write too much code.